# Using Django and ccextractor to generate subtitles from video

Tags: python, django, cloud, video-processing, video-subtitles

I want to create a site which takes video, upload it to the server, process it and return subtitles generated from that video. I searched on internet and got to know about ccextractor. Though, site has something about usage with python but it's bit of a mess there. I couldn't understand just how to use it with python. I am thinking of using subprocesses along with ccextractor command line tool but unable to figure it out how to provide uploaded video to the input of the command.
Solutions and Suggestions would be appreciated alot.
Thanks

Comment: What video formats are you supporting on your website? Do you have an example, of each format, with subtitles? It might to easier to write your own code to extract the subtitle text from the video file bytes according to the format it saved as...

Answer (score 0):

Install cc extractor

For ubuntu,

sudo apt update

sudo apt -y install ccextractor

Clone cc extractor from github to videos folder in our system

https://github.com/CCExtractor/ccextractor

git clone https://github.com/CCExtractor/ccextractor

cd ~/Videos

cd ccextractor/linux

./build

Right click video -properties- parent folder path copy

./ccextractor pathname

./ccextractor /home/user/Videos

Now open the video. Then you can see the video with subtitles :)